# Redirect Page If Any Action Happend

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a kiosk application. In this application, if index page opened with post values (index.html?location=5) except index page with no post value and any action happened in 60 seconds like mouse over or typing, redirect to index page with no value. I am using this code but..

```
function setIdle(cb, seconds) {
    var timer; 
    var interval = seconds * 1000;

    function refresh() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(cb, interval);
    };

    $(document).on('keypress, click', refresh);

    $(document).on('mouseover', refresh);

    var parts = location.pathname.split('/');

    if(parts[parts.length - 1] != 'index.html') {
        location.href = 'index.html';
    }

    refresh();
}

setIdle(function() {
    location.href = './index.html';
}, 60);
```

When I run this code, it is refreshing index page with no value. I can not figure it out how can I do that ?

I want to do

if index.html?location = 5  wait for 60 seconds for any mouse or keyboard action then return index.html

if index.html do not check mouse or keyboard

Answer (score 0):

`setIdle()` gets called only once (when the page first loads), and this is where your conditional logic is. `refresh()` is what's actually doing the redirect, but this is not inside any sort of `if`, and so it gets called every single time regardless of which page you're on.

Why not ignore the idle function completely if the page is `index.html`?

```
function setIdle(cb, seconds) {
    var timer; 
    var interval = seconds * 1000;

    function refresh() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(cb, interval);
    };

    $(document).on('keypress, click', refresh);
    $(document).on('mouseover', refresh);

    refresh();
}

var parts = location.pathname.split('/');

//If page is not index.html
if(parts[parts.length - 1] != 'index.html') {

    //initialize the "idle" functionality
    setIdle(function() {
        location.href = './index.html';
    }, 60);

}
```

Comment: I edited the my question. I did not explain that. Sorry.